# How to Calculate Unique values using 2 column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below dataframe, I need to groupby all user_id and calculate unique categories corresponding to each user_id

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uH3U.png)

[Input Is like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uH3U.png)

And The Output should be Like

[This is the expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAmRr.png)

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Please add your sample data and desired output to your post, not as images.

Comment: I have edited my question and added snippet of expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the distinct categories for each user, one way is to use a simple **distinct()**. This will give you each combination of the *user_id* and the *category* columns:

```py
df.select("user_id", "category").distinct()
```

Another approach is to use **collect_set()** as an aggregation function. It will automatically get rid of the duplicates. This way there will be one record for each *user_id*, with all the categories aggregated to a struct field.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set

df.groupBy("user_id").agg(collect_set("category")).display()
```

The first approach looks like the one that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the ans, but the above solution is finding count for categories, but I need to take out the categorical values. i.e. unique categories corresponding to each user